Modifying partially the book class chapter code using l3 language
Consider the following code, which is an extract from a much longer code, which I tried to reduce to a more reasonable size.
What it does?
The code provides a package, that overwrites the chapter sectioning functions and methods of book.cls or scrbook.cls to enable the users to write short formatters as to how the heading should be shaped and typeset.
Programming targets

To untangle the original code book.cls code so is fully procedural.
Conditionals should not be repeated in different functions.

The user provided function should not need to repeat any tests.
Just receive input and provide output.

Use l3 language

Must work well with hyperref.


Question
I am looking for a general code review and suggestions and how to fix some issues with the code shown. The first, if you run the code both with scrbook and book you will notice than in the frontmatter scrbook shows the section number a 1. whereas the book shows it Djikstra style like 0.1. Second issue I would like to get rid of secdef.
    \documentclass[twocolumn,twoside]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[welsh]{babel}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    % begin package
    \begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{explora.sty}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \makeatletter
    \def\namespace{expl}
    
    % New booleans not used at the moment
    %\bool_new:c {\namespace _secnumdepth_bool}
    %\bool_new:c {\namespace _mainmatter_bool}
    %\bool_new:  \\namespace _twocolumn_bool}
    %
    % Create variant
    \cs_generate_variant:Nn \prg_new_conditional:Npnn { cpnn }
    % new conditionals
    
    \prg_new_conditional:cpnn {\namespace _if_twocolumn:} {p,T,F,TF} 
      {
        \legacy_if:nTF{@twocolumn}{\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}
      }
    
    \prg_new_conditional:cpnn {\namespace _if_mainmatter:} {p,T,F,TF} 
      {
        \legacy_if:nTF{@mainmatter}{\prg_return_true:}{\prg_return_false:}
      }
    
    %=============== Main ============ you can move it at the bottom if yoy like
    % Pascal-like
    %
    % Starts the ball rolling
    \cs_set:Npn\chapter{ \use:c{\namespace _chapter_main}}
    
    % 
    \exp_args:Nc
    \NewDocumentCommand {\namespace _chapter_main}{}
    { \tl_use:c {\namespace _chapter_main_opening_tl}
                        \thispagestyle{plain}%
                        \global\@topnum\z@
                        \@afterindentfalse
                        \secdef\@chapter\@schapter
    }                
    
    \tl_set:cn {\namespace _chapter_main_opening_tl} {
      \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
    }
    
    
    \cs_set:Npn \@chapter[#1]#2{
      
      \use:c{\namespace _chapter_main_add_to_contents:n}{#1}{#2}
      % call the typesetting function which will call
      % makechapterhead or makeschapterhead after checking first
      % for one or two columns
      \use:c{\namespace _chapter_main_typeset:n}{#2} 
      \par
      
      \@afterheading  
     }
    
    \cs_set:Npn \usertemplate {
      \huge\bfseries \@chapapp
                \space \thechapter
    }
    
    \cs_set:Npn \usertemplatestar#1{
       \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    }
    
    
    \cs_set:Npn\@makechapterhead #1{
      
      \vspace*{40\p@}%
      {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
             \usertemplate
    %        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp
    %            \space \thechapter
            \par\nobreak
            \vskip 20\p@
          \fi
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \usertemplatestar{#1}
        %\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
      }}
    
      
    \cs_set:Npn\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                       \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                     \else
                       \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                       %\@afterheading
                     \fi}
                     
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
      \vspace*{50\p@}%
      {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
      }}
    
    \cs_set:cpn {\namespace _chapter_main_add_to_contents:n} #1 #2 %<- comes from @chapter
    { 
      \int_compare:nNnTF {\value{secnumdepth}}>{-1}
        {
           \use:c{\namespace _if_mainmatter:TF} 
             { \refstepcounter{chapter}
               \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
               \addcontentslinenumbered:n{#1}                                   
             }
             {
               \addcontentslinenonumber:n{#1}
             } 
        }
        {
          \addcontentslinenonumber:n{#1}
        } 
        
      }
    
    \cs_set_protected:cpn {\namespace _chapter_main_typeset:n} #1
    {  
       \if@twocolumn
                          \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#1}]%
                        \else
                          \@makechapterhead{#1}%
                          %\@afterheading
                        \fi  
    }
    
    
    \cs_new_protected:Npn \addcontentslinenumbered:n #1
      { 
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                       {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\itshape #1}
     
      }
    
    \cs_new:Npn \addcontentslinenonumber:n #1
      {
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
      }
    
    \makeatother
    \ExplSyntaxOff
    \end{filecontents*}
    \usepackage{explora}
    \usepackage[raiselinks,colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
    
    \frontmatter
    \onecolumn
    \chapter{Preface}
    \lipsum[1]\par
    
    
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \section{First section in preface}
    \twocolumn
    \chapter{Acknowledgements}
    \mainmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \pagestyle{headings}
    \part{General}
    \chapter{First Title }
    \chapter[zzzz]{Testing a Longer Title but short in ToC 2}
    %
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \section{First section}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{document}


you shouldn't do it like this in a koma classes. It has its own method to configure headings and you are breaking them. Imho it is a rather bad idea to use something generic like expl as namespace prefix, and you naming of variables like bools are wrong, they miss the \l_ or \g_ prefix. Also be aware that nowadays is it not enough to think about hyperref compability, you also need to think about tagging support compability (and we will extend heading commands in this context).

as Ulrike says you should not use expl as the module name. If you want to keep the module name abstaracy and not simply  \l_yannisl_chapter_main_opening_tl then you could use l3doc and ``\l_@@_chapter_main_opening_tl where@@will be replaced while extracting. This is more efficient than using:c` everywere which uses extra expansions and a lot more tokens.

@UlrikeFischer  Thanks, I used namespace as in my longer code I use a ..dtx with l3doc  and gets replaced with the @@ method. On naming the package in the MWE is named explora hence the exp prefix. In my real package the prefix is phd in honour of my late professor, who use to say that anyone that managed to write a thesis using LaTeX deserved a phd just for this!

defining expl3 functions with \NewDocumentCommand isn't necessarily an error but it is mixing layers in unexpected ways and is not usually recommended. \NewDocumentCommand {\namespace _chapter_main}{} the defined command isn't a document command and so should be defined using an expl3 declaration not \NewDocumentCommand

@DavidCarlisle Please see my response. This was only done for the MWE.

well if you ask for code review and almost every line of code in the code shown has this obvious issue then it makes reviewing the code without mentioning that rather hard.

You could instead have shown the code as extracted from the dtx, which had the @@ replaced, but using single tokens not \namespace and :c arguments

@DavidCarlisle True, I should have shown the .dtx. As to the abuse of the  \NewDocumentCommand  is such a useful command, I now see many packages using it also for internal ex. tcolorbox. We need something similar for internal in the kernel.

No. By design expl3 commands do not have optional arguments or star forms or other features that NewDocumentCommand makes it easy to define, The idea is to separate out the programming concerns. Define teh basic functionality using L3 and just mandatory arguments, then separately at the top level define a latex2e style interface using NewDocumentCommand. You could define other interfaces (xml or context or whatever) to the same functionality implemented using your expl3 code just by changing teh NewDocumentCommand to declare a different top level interface

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

why does your example load welsh hyphenation etc. when the content consists entirely of english and latin?

@cfr  When testing I always use a random language to ensure that translation of strings is done properly. It was just your lucky day:) I also normally disable actives, not in this example to see if anything by-passes Babel's mechanism of disabling actives. If = is active there is a very good chance it is not disabled and messes with key-val lists.

@yannisl you can't test if the mechanism disables actives successfully with a language which makes nothing active in the first place.

@cfr  For actives I normally use Turkish or Swedish the latter probably has the most and the former by-passes. This was a MWE to try unsuccessfully I admit to demonstrate some concepts and ask for feedback.

sorry, I did realise this was not relevant to your question. but given the people you'd already had review your code, I wouldn't have dared say anything relevant ;).
